# Update React component state from jQuery in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, react-typescript

We have started to embed React components in a mature ASP.NET Core MVC Web App. In one such component we pass a container div and two form input elements to the React component:

cshtml:

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        React.Components.Create(
            document.getElementById("containerDivId"),
            document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(m => m.SharedFields.FooId)"),
            document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(m => m.SharedFields.BarId)"));
    });     
    ...
```

componentFactory.tsx:

```ts
Create(rootElement: HTMLElement, fooIdInput: HTMLInputElement, barIdInput: HTMLInputElement): void {
    const root = createRoot(rootElement);
    root.render(
        <StrictMode>
            <Controller
                fooIdInput={fooIdInput}
                barIdInput={barIdInput}                    
            />
        </StrictMode>
    );
},
```

In the Controller we add functionality in React to change the values and then update the input elements:

```ts
// update bound fooId / barId html inputs
useEffect(() => {
    props.fooIdInput.value = vm.fooId?.toString() ?? "";
    const e = new Event("change");
    props.fooIdInput.dispatchEvent(e);
}, [vm.fooId]);
useEffect(() => {
    props.barIdInput.value = vm.barId?.toString() ?? "";
    const e = new Event("change");
    props.barIdInput.dispatchEvent(e);
}, [vm.barId]);
```

There is a new requirement to clear the input elements if another input on the MVC form is changed. It's relatively simple to clear the input values in jQuery:

```js
function onOtherIdChanged() {
    $("#SharedFields_FooId").val(null).trigger("change");
    $("#SharedFields_BarId").val(null).trigger("change");
}
```

but this won't be reflected automatically in the React component state. Is there a better way of initialising a React component with MVC form inputs that allows for those inputs to be cleared if they are changed on the MVC side?

We can achieve this by dispatching a custom event on the window and listening for it in the component, but this seems like overkill and not necessarily the right solution given that it is used multiple times in the application and this functionality is required in only one use case.